# Call Spring Boot controller from thymeleaf dropdown select

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need my Spring Boot web application to make a REST call when the user changes the selected item from this Thymeleaf dropdown list:

```
<form th:action="@{/getdata}" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select th:name="thetablename">
                    <option th:if="${thetablename.isEmpty()}">Select Table</option>
                    <option th:each="table: ${tables}"
                            th:value="${table.tablename}"
                            th:selected="${table.tablename eq thetablename}"
                            th:text="${table.displayname}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" th:value="${buttonlabel}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- data shows here after submit -->

</form>
```

The user selects from a list of db tables. When they click `Submit`, the Controller makes a REST call to retrieve that table’s data, which is returned and displayed.

Can Thymeleaf call the controller when the dropdown selection changes, rather than after Submit? I don't see this approach demo'd in the [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html).

Comment: Have you tried using the onChange() value in the select element?

Comment: I have, but without success. I get a syntax error in my IntelliJ IDE when I try th:onchange="@{/getdata}". Plus the controller still does not get called on change after I added that - which has made me whether that kind of dynamic approach is possible within Thymeleaf.

Comment: easiest: `<select onchange="this.form.submit()" th:...>`

Comment: xerx593 That's it! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!